# Makefile auto-dependency generation

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying to see auto generated dependency the makefile is below:

```
  OBJS := main.o 

  run : $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(OBJS) -o run -lstdc++

  -include $(OBJS:.o=.d)

 %.o : %.cpp
      $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $*.cpp -o $*.o

 %.d : %.cpp
       @set -e; rm -f $@; \
       $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
       echo "creating dependency file."; \
       sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
       rm -f $@.$$$$

  # remove compilation products
  clean :
         rm -f run *.o *.d*
```

But the makefile generate a huge list of dependency in main.d but the actual needed is the first few lines. So where I am getting wrong?

Comment: What contents are in `main.d` that you don't think belong there?

Comment: `main.o main.d : main.cpp main.h \
** /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iostream \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h \
 /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/os_defines.h \
 /usr/include/features.h /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h \**`
Ideally it should show only first line (**main.o main.d : main.cpp main.h**) . Why the remaining lines are comming and the output expected was **main.o: main.cpp main.h**?

Comment: Your code is clearly including some of them as well (and they are including the other headers). The prerequisites can't stop at the first-level included header files or they will miss things. Is that `**` literal?

Comment: Then how to get the desired output?

Comment: Do it manually if you really care about not having the extra information there. But the point is that extra information is *correct* and you don't ever need to care about it.

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of that by modifying the sed command if yes please do the same?

Comment: Possibly. I'd have to see a fair bit more example output to be sure it worked correctly. But you really don't want to do that. The output you have is the right output. Anything you strip off makes the prerequisite information incomplete and wrong.

Comment: If possible then modify the makefile and update it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying but if you are asking me to fix that `sed`/etc. for what you want I'm not going to do that. I don't, offhand, know what I would need to change. Without seeing more example files I wouldn't trust that I could get it right and I don't believe the task is a useful one as it just makes the `.d` file less correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
  OBJS := main.o 

  run : $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(OBJS) -o run -lstdc++

  -include $(OBJS:.o=.d)

 %.o : %.cpp
      $(CC) -c -MMD -MP $(CFLAGS) $*.cpp -o $*.o

  # remove compilation products
  clean :
         rm -f run *.o *.d*
```